# Failed to resolve: com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0

Tags: android, maven

> ```
> CoverFlow is pushed to Maven Central as a AAR, so you just need to add the it's dependency to local build.gradle (usually locate in app module). Because of this libary is build in the min-sdk is 15, so your project must set same as it:
> ```

but when I try to use this library I got this error

> Failed to resolve: com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0

this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.maysara.theproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: But are you using mavenCentral() repository, or jcenter()?

Comment: both mavenCentral() and jcenter()

Answer (score 3):

Add to your graldle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

At first set  **minSdkVersion 15** instead of **16**

Whats your Logcat says

> so you just need to add the it's dependency to local build.gradle
>   (usually locate in app module). Because of this libary is build in the
>   min-sdk is 15, so your project must set same as it:

```
defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.example.maysara.theproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

**FYI**

Enable publishing AAR file to Maven Central

```
repositories {
      jcenter() // or  mavenCentral()
  }
```

Comment: It's completely fine to have minSdk set to a higher value than the one in the library, it's important that it's not lower.

Comment: and also I should add 
            mavenCentral()
 thanks for everybody

Comment: @Maysara, This answer doesn't even mention mavenCentral(), and yet you mark it as accepted, ignoring the other answer, which is correct.

Comment: @Egor yes yes ,As per our SO rule